# Javascript Switch Statement to fill a table

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a table to log in stress level through the click of a button which leads to a prompt, i got the first line to work and it fills in the table but i don't know how to take it to the next line because if the button is clicked again the input for the prompt refreshes and prints in the same cell. I hope that makes sense i'm quite new in coding so forgive me if i dont make sense.

here is my HTML code followed by the JavaScript;

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="project.html">Occupational Stress Monitor</a>
    <form class="form-inline">
      <button id= "record-button" class="btn btn-md btn-light" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Click Here to Record Stress">Record</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav> 

<h1>Stress Log</h1>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class="heading">Day of the Week</th>
    <th class="heading">Stress Level</th>
    <th class="heading">Cause of Stress</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Monday</td>
    <td  id="Monday"></td>
    <td id="stressor1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Tuesday</td>
    <td id="Tuesday"></td>
    <td id="stressor2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Wednesday</td>
    <td id="Wednesday"></td>
    <td id="stressor3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Thursday</td>
    <td id="Thursday"></td>
    <td id="stressor4"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Friday</td>
    <td id="Friday"></td>
    <td id="stressor5"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var record = document.getElementById("record-button");
var person = ["Good", "Ok", "Bad"]; 

record.onclick = function () {
  var person = prompt ("How are you feeling today?-Good,Ok or Bad");  
  document.getElementById("Monday").innerHTML = person;

  if (person !== "Good") {
    var cause = prompt ("What is causing your stress?");
    document.getElementById("stressor1").innerHTML = cause;
   }
}
```

Comment: You need to iterate over the possible values (days). For a simple solution you could create an array containing all the days `days = ['Monday', ..., 'Friday']` and set a value `var index = 0;` to keep track of which day. Then inside your function do `var day =  days[index]; index++;` That should be enough to get you started

Answer (score 0):

**You can do it something like this**

**What i have done is.**

Used a variable array called days which have all the days and one variable called last to keep track of which day is inserted before the current click event.Than in the onclick function every time i am selecting the current clicked day from array and updating last by 1.

```js
var record = document.getElementById("record-button");
var person = ["Good", "Ok", "Bad"]; 
var days = ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday",]
var last = 0;

    record.onclick = function (){
    if(last < 5)
     {
     var person = prompt ("How are you feeling today?-Good,Ok or Bad");  
     document.getElementById(`${days[last]}`).innerHTML = person;

    if (person !== "Good"){
    var cause = prompt ("What is causing your stress?");
    document.getElementById(`stressor${last+1}`).innerHTML = cause;
   }
   last++
  }
  }
```

```html
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <div class="container">
       <a class="navbar-brand" href="project.html">Occupational Stress Monitor</a>
       <form class="form-inline">
         <button id= "record-button" class="btn btn-md btn-light" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Click Here to Record Stress">Record</button>
       </form>
      </div>
       </nav> 

    <h1>Stress Log</h1>
    <table>
     <tr>
      <th class="heading">Day of the Week</th>
      <th class="heading">Stress Level</th>
      <th class="heading">Cause of Stress</th>
     </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Monday</td>
         <td  id="Monday"></td>
         <td id="stressor1"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Tuesday</td>
         <td id="Tuesday"></td>
         <td id="stressor2"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>Wednesday</td>
         <td id="Wednesday"></td>
         <td id="stressor3"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>Thursday</td>
         <td id="Thursday"></td>
         <td id="stressor4"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>Friday</td>
         <td id="Friday"></td>
         <td id="stressor5"></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: @AishaUmara you can upvote and mark as correct answer :p anyways happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use querySelector to achieve that behaviour.

```
var record = document.getElementById("record-button");
var recordIndicator = ["Good", "Ok", "Bad"]; 
var cellCounter = 2

record.onclick = function (){
  var person = prompt ("How are you feeling today?-Good,Ok or Bad") ; 

  document.querySelector(`table tr:nth-child(${cellCounter}) td:nth-child(2)`).innerHTML = "person";
  var cause = prompt ("What is causing your stress?");
  document.querySelector(`table tr:nth-child(${cellCounter}) td:nth-child(3)`).innerHTML = "cause";
   cellCounter++;
}
```

I have used String literals to use the cellCounter variable inside querySelector.
To learn more about [String literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and [query Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) you can visit respective links.
Happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, i would have to learn more to understand your code but it is very helpful. Thanks!